# Which arbitrary length limitation does Entity Framework 6.1.3 impose on you?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my program, I configure the model for Entity Framework 6.1.3 using the Fluent API. Amongst others I have a number of invocations like this:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.SomeAssociation)
.WithMany(t => t.KnownInstances)
.HasForeignKey(d => d.SomeAssociationID)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This should obviously generate foreign keys when I invoke `Add-Migration`. Several of these invocations of `HasForeignKey(...)` actually do NOT generate any foreign keys, but if I shorten the schema name for the tables involved, the foreign keys gets generated.

`Add-Migration` doesn't inform that some limit on length has been exceeded. In this way Entity Framework 6.1.3 silently invites for inconsistency in the database, because you probably don't notice, that Entity Framework silently has disobeyed the request to create foreign keys.

Therefore my question is, which (arbitrary) lengths of names does Entity Framework 6.1.3 impose on you?

Is there a way to make `Add-Migration` to complain about exceeding some limits instead of silently disobeying what you've specified using the fluent API?